# New title of outlines is not saved

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'd like to change title of outlines using iText 7. I've written the following code but in the resulting pdf there are no changes. Why?

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(
    new PdfReader(INPUT),
    new PdfWriter(OUTPUT),
    new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

try (pdfDocument) {
   List<PdfOutline> outlines = pdfDocument.getOutlines(false).getAllChildren();
   outlines.forEach(o -> o.setTitle("Title"));
}
```

Comment: You work in append mode. Quite likely you have to mark the containing indirect object as updated.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for that.  Could you point to some documentation, please? I couldn't find it on my own.

Comment: @Alexey already answered in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mkl has correctly pointed out in his comment, working in append mode imposes additional requirements on the modified objects to be marked as such. iText should do it behind the scenes for the most operations, but in this case it does not, which is a bug. A simple solution is available, though. You can fetch the necessary PDF object and mark it as modified yourself. Here is the full solution:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(
    new PdfReader(INPUT),
    new PdfWriter(OUTPUT),
    new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

try (pdfDocument) {
    List<PdfOutline> outlines = pdfDocument.getOutlines(false).getAllChildren();
    for (PdfOutline outline : outlines) {
        outline.setTitle("Title");
        outline.getContent().setModified();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have already changed the accept mark to your answer as it the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

By using this code, I was able to update all the outlines to "Title":

```
try (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(INPUT_FILE), 
        new PdfWriter(OUTPUT_FILE))) {
    List<PdfOutline> outlines = pdfDocument.getOutlines(false).getAllChildren();
    outlines.forEach(o -> o.setTitle("Title"));
}
```

How are you initializing [pdfDocument](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.8/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html)? Maybe you can upload the PDF file?

Comment: It is a bug in iText7. I used another construcor (with `StampingProperties`) and it fails when it comes to saving outlines. The constructor you have used doesn't have that bug.

Comment: @menteith, can you update the question with how you've used the constructor? I am the Technical Product Manager at iText, so I will be able to follow this up

Comment: well, to be fair, useAppendMode() means: "Defines if the document will be edited in append mode.". The changing the title Edition is not an "appending operation".

Comment: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.8/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/StampingProperties.html#appendMode

Comment: Thanks, I knew that page. However, what I meant is why I cannot use `appendMode` in a such situation.

Comment: Upvoting this answer as the solution by @Alexey Subach better asnwers my question.